# Excel: Is it possible to reference the currently-selected cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to select a cell and then have a formula reference that specific cell?

For instance, if I clicked on C3, my calculated cell would then show whatever value is in C3, and it would update to a new value if I clicked on C4.  Can I do that?

Comment: VBA in a Worksheet_Select event would do this easily.  Theoretically you could use `=CELL("contents")`, but that would require you to recalculate every time you change the selection for it to change.

Comment: @ScottCraner That might be manageable.  The tricky part is that I would need to reference the selected cell from Worksheet 1 to populate info into Worksheet 2.  From what I'm reading, that could be a bit more work.  What do you think?

Comment: `Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Target.Value`

Comment: Copy and paste?